# copy() and ImageMagick

Tags: php

I'm coping external file with `copy()` and then resize it with ImageMagick.
Will php wait until image been downloaded and only after that begin converting image ?

For example

```
copy("http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png","newfile.png");
```

Here I convert downloaded image `exec("nice -n 19 convert -resize 500x500 ....`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will be wait for it,

But better in this way to use [curl](http://php.net/curl) with timeout

Comment: Note that you should be able to specify a timeout *(and do other stuff)* with `copy`, using http://fr.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php